# How can I check whether a variable is defined in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a program in node.js which is actually js.

I have a  variable :

```
var query = azure.TableQuery...
```

looks this line of the code is not executing some times.

my question is :

How can I do a condition like:

```
if this variable is defined do this.
else do this.
```

I cannot do in js `(query!= null)`

I want to see if this variable is defined do some thing. how to do this

Comment: `if (query != undefined) { /* defined */ }`

Comment: Why isn't it defined sometimes? Does `azure.TableQuery` actually return `undefined`?

Comment: Are you checking for undefined, specifically, or are you checking for null, empty arrays, empty objects, 0...?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do some asynchronous stuff ( `TableQuery` ) in a synchronous way. Don't do that, use callbacks. I'm sure that this `azure` thing provides this functionality.

Comment: @H2CO3 !=undefined also returns true on a null value. He needs to use the stricter !==

Answer (score 128):

```
if ( typeof query !== 'undefined' && query )
{
  //do stuff if query is defined and not null
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: can you please let me know why you changed and added typeof and &&

Comment: "not null" should be "not null, zero, false or anything else that evaluates as false"

Comment: Because a variable in js can be null or undefined. Those are different states. So we have to check both scenarios

Comment: typeof query !== 'undefined' just checks if the variable is not undefined
if ( query ) check if the variable is not null

Comment: To test both, you can do `query == null`. That'll test for `null` or `undefined`, but no other falsey values. Or just do `query === undefined` to test for that value alone.

Comment: @user1689607 that's not correct. It will not test for undefined.
Just try if ( someVariableThatDoesntExist == null ) you will get an error

Comment: @KirillIvlev: There's a difference between a variable being *undeclared* and being *undefined*. If the variable is *undeclared*, you should declare it. If you get an error, then that's a helpful reminder that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @user1689607 ok in that case I agree. But best practice is still to check it against null and undefined. And the asker says that sometimes  the variable declaration doesn't execute

Comment: Why did someone downvote my answer? The author clearly says that sometimes the variable is not declared(perhaps it's just in a timeout or something)

Comment: @Kirill, OP says "defined" and does not exclude `null`, `0`, `""` or `false` as valid values. In its current form, your answer makes far too many assumptions.

Comment: the undefined needs to be without quotes for nodejs atleast, that change made it work for me.

Answer (score 37):

Determine if property is existing (but is not a falsy value):

```
if (typeof query !== 'undefined' && query !== null){
   doStuff();
}
```

Usually using

```
if (query){
   doStuff();
}
```

is sufficient. Please note that:

```
if (!query){
   doStuff();
}
```

doStuff() will execute even if query was an existing variable with falsy value (0, false, undefined or null)

Btw, there's a sexy coffeescript way of doing this:

```
if object?.property? then doStuff()
```

which compiles to:

```
if ((typeof object !== "undefined" && object !== null ? object.property : void 0) != null) 

{
  doStuff();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work in case query in integer 0 though `if (query){
   doStuff();
}`

Answer (score 28):

For me, an expression like

```
if (typeof query !== 'undefined' && query !== null){
   // do stuff
}
```

is more complicated than I want for how often I want to use it. That is, testing if a variable is defined/null is something I do frequently. I want such a test to be simple. To resolve this, I first tried to define the above code as a function, but node just gives me a syntax error, telling me the parameter to the function call is undefined. Not useful! So, searching about and working on this bit, I found a solution. Not for everyone perhaps. My solution involves using [Sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org) to define a macro. Here's how I did it:

Here's the macro (filename: macro.sjs):

```
// I had to install sweet using:
// npm install --save-dev
// See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetbuild
// Followed instructions from https://github.com/mozilla/sweet.js/wiki/node-loader

// Initially I just had "($x)" in the macro below. But this failed to match with 
// expressions such as "self.x. Adding the :expr qualifier cures things. See
// http://jlongster.com/Writing-Your-First-Sweet.js-Macro

macro isDefined {
  rule {
    ($x:expr)
  } => {
    (( typeof ($x) === 'undefined' || ($x) === null) ? false : true)
  }
}


// Seems the macros have to be exported
// https://github.com/mozilla/sweet.js/wiki/modules

export isDefined;
```

Here's an example of usage of the macro (in example.sjs):

```
function Foobar() {
    var self = this;

    self.x = 10;

    console.log(isDefined(y)); // false
    console.log(isDefined(self.x)); // true
}

module.exports = Foobar;
```

And here's the main node file:

```
var sweet = require('sweet.js');

// load all exported macros in `macros.sjs`
sweet.loadMacro('./macro.sjs');

// example.sjs uses macros that have been defined and exported in `macros.sjs`
var Foobar = require('./example.sjs');

var x = new Foobar();
```

A downside of this, aside from having to install Sweet, setup the macro, and load Sweet in your code, is that it can complicate error reporting in Node. It adds a second layer of parsing. Haven't worked with this much yet, so shall see how it goes first hand. I like Sweet though and I miss macros so will try to stick with it!

Answer (score 8):

If your variable is not declared nor defined:

```
if ( typeof query !== 'undefined' ) { ... }
```

If your variable is declared but undefined. (assuming the case here is that the variable might not be defined but it can be any other falsy value like `false` or `""`)

```
if ( query ) { ... }
```

If your variable is declared but can be `undefined` or `null`:

```
if ( query != null ) { ... } // undefined == null
```

Answer (score 3):

For easy tasks I often simply do it like:

```
var undef;

// Fails on undefined variables
if (query !== undef) {
    // variable is defined
} else {
    // else do this
}
```

Or if you simply want to check for a nulled value too..

```
var undef;

// Fails on undefined variables
// And even fails on null values
if (query != undef) {
    // variable is defined and not null
} else {
    // else do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing property checking on an object! If you want to check a property exists (but can be values such as null or 0 in addition to truthy values), the **in** operator can make for some nice syntax.

```
var foo = { bar: 1234, baz: null };
console.log("bar in foo:", "bar" in foo); // true
console.log("baz in foo:", "baz" in foo); // true
console.log("otherProp in foo:", "otherProp" in foo) // false
console.log("__proto__ in foo:", "__proto__" in foo) // true
```

As you can see, the **__proto__** property is going to be thrown here. This is true for all inherited properties. For further reading, I'd recommend the MDN page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 0):

You could use double exclamation mark `!!` to check if something is defined and not null.

`!!null` returns `false`.
`!!undefined` will also return `false`.

But if you define a variable for example `const a = 1`, then `!!a` will return `true`.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the answer itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of options here, but I would say, that in some cases the code will execute not the way expected, or throw an error. If you want a safe way, use `try` `catch`:

```js
try {
  I_dont_exist
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Variable is not defined')
}
```