# Is it possible to include feature that depend on if the user as installed a certain package (optionalFeature)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I am writing a module and I want that if an user have installed in his project `react-intl`, to export an advanced component with translation feature.

This way I don't have to maintain two version of my components to avoid installation warning.

I have been trying to play with `optionalDepenceny`, but they are installed on the project of the user when he install my package.

Typically, this is the source I am trying to import

```
/**
*
* ToggleOption
*
*/

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Option from 'bootstrap-styled/lib/Option';

let injectIntl;
let intlShape;

// this make react-intl optional to our component and our module
try {
  const reactIntl = require('react-intl'); // eslint-disable-line
  injectIntl = reactIntl.injectIntl; // eslint-disable-line
  intlShape = reactIntl.intlShape; // eslint-disable-line
} catch (er) {
  injectIntl = null;
  intlShape = null;
}

/**
 * This component is automatically used when using `<Toggle />`
 * If you need a different option tag, instead just pass the prop `optionTag` of `<Toggle />`.
 */
const ToggleOption = ({
  tag: Tag,
  value,
  message,
  intl,
}) => (
  <Tag value={value}>
    {message && intl ? intl.formatMessage(message) : value}
  </Tag>
);

ToggleOption.defaultProps = {
  tag: Option,
};

/* eslint-disable react/require-default-props */
ToggleOption.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Replace the default component tag by the one specified. Can be:
   */
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.element,
    PropTypes.func,
  ]),
  /**
   * The value
   */
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  /**
   * react-intl messages (optional)
   */
  message: PropTypes.object,
};

let exported = ToggleOption; // eslint-disable-line import/no-mutable-exports

if (intlShape) {
  /** @ignore */
  ToggleOption.propTypes.intl = intlShape.isRequired;
  exported = injectIntl(ToggleOption);
}

export default exported;
```

Is there a way to configure my module in order to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional dependencies in your `package.json` are always installed as default. To avoid them you have to install with:

```
npm install [PACKAGE] --no-optional
```

You can note it, for example, in your description, like I do: https://github.com/Llorx/updated-require

PS: Your code is fine.

Comment: I guess I helped you pass the 6K mark. I didn't notice at first, but it looks nice :-)

Comment: @Myst Exactly haha. Thnx ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a module was already included / required by [testing if it's module (it's "namespace") was define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335873/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-node-js) (`if (typeof Module !== "undefined")...`).

Another option, if you want to include / require a module that might have been installed is to [surround the include / require statement with a try / catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197795/handle-errors-thrown-by-require-module-in-node-js).

Good luck!

EDIT:

As for using [optionalDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies), it won't change your code - you will still have to perform the same checks using try/catch.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem he has, but I guess that he is asking about how to avoid installation of the package, as its optional. PS: I don't downvoted.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález - thanks for trying to explain. I guess my answer wasn't the best fit for what OP was asking... but maybe I really didn't understand the question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Also, JavaScript don't have namespaces for installed modules. You need to require them beforehand. The closest thing is to check for global variables, as in browsers the typical (non webpack) way of injecting libraries is by adding them to the window, so you can check them with `if (window.Module)` or `if (typeof Module !== "undefined")`, but `if (Module...` will throw a `Module is not defined` error if the Module is not defined.

Comment: I was going to reply the try/catch thing, but saw your -1 so I tried to understand the question in other way xD Is a bit unclear.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález - thanks for the catch. I fixed the missing `typeof`. As for namespaces, I fixed that, but I left it in parentheses. I guess the terminology might be different from C++ or Rust, but the global variables perform pretty much the same function (defining all the functions as members of that variable prevents collisions)...

Comment: Woah! I made you reach 10k! I feel important! xDD

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález 